# Zuul proxy, eureka server and angular 6

Tags: angular, angular-routing, netflix-eureka, netflix-zuul

I am new to zuul proxy and eureka server.
I have created two microservices and have integrated them on eureka server.
Now using zuul I'm able to have inter communication between these two and zuul routes the request also to these both microservices.
Now, I've one angular 6 application which is also to be integrated with zuul, such that calling the zuul service with some specified Port number should redirect to my angular application.
Is this possible? If yes then how?

Answer (score 0):

I think this should be vice-versa. i.e. from the angular application, call the microservice (i.e. the application) url which is exposed by zuul gateway and the gateway will automatically redirect to the appropriate microservice for fetching the response.

Comment: Hi @Daniel atlas, we have done this thing like calling microservice from UI. But as per our requirement, we need zuul to be responsible for routing to UI application. So basically we need gateway to redirect to UI application. Is this possible?